Confusing usage of 「これ」 (with an unclear referent) and 「の」 (which could be possesive or appositional)

「地 球にはドーホーを捜しに来ました。」
「どーほー？」
ちょっと迷ってから変換する。あ、同胞ね。え、これの仲間？

The context is that the main character meets a peculiar person who is wearing an astronaut suit while fishing. The first person speaking is the astronaut-suit-wearing person, and the second person is the main character. 「これ」 and 「の」 here are really confusing me.
Theory 1: 「これ」 refers to the astronaut-suit-wearing person — This would mean the sentence translates as "(That means that 同胞 means) a friend of this person?". This doesn't feel like it fits, because the main character previously used 「こいつ」 for her. Why would she suddenly change her pronoun in this sentence?
Theory 2: 「の」 is appositional — This would translate as "This (同胞), a friend?". This results in the same meaning as Theory 1. I don't feel confident in this theory as I'm not sure whether appositional の can be used for non-humans.
Theory 3: 「これ」 refers to the main character. This one seems the most unlikely to me. The fan translation translates this sentence as "What did she mean by brethren? Her friends?", so the translation also doesn't agree with me on this.
What exactly do 「これ」 and 「の」 mean here?

Your Theory 1 is the correct interpretation. "これの仲間?" means "(Does 同胞 mean) a friend of this (being)?".
The switch from こいつ to これ is likely because the speaker is questioning the nature of the "being" in front of her. While こいつ is already a fairly unfriendly pronoun if used to refer to a stranger, it at least assumes a human-like being capable of human-like communication. In contrast, これ is primarily for non-humans. The main character may have chosen this pronoun because she was starting to wonder whether to treat "her" like a person.

Thanks! Seems like I was overthinking it. By the way, can the appositional の be used like I mentioned above?

@Tree No, the correct word order for appositive-の is this. For example, 仲間の猿 means "a monkey companion", and 仲間のこいつ can mean "this guy, (who is) my buddy" or "this buddy of mine here".
